# How can I find \$\small V_{GS}\$ in this question?

Tags: transistors, circuit-analysis, nmos

[image]

My attempt:

DC ANALYSIS

Using voltage divider: $$V_{G0}=\frac{200\ \mathrm{k\Omega}}{300\ \mathrm{k\Omega}} \cdot 3\ \mathrm{V} = 2\ \mathrm{V}$$

By KCL $$I_{D0}=I_{D1}=I_{B}=I_{D}=1\ \mathrm{mA}$$

Since we assume SAT:$$I_{D0}=0.5(V_{GS_0}-V_{TN})^2(1+\lambda_0 \cdot V_{DS_0})$$

How do I find \$\small V_{GS_0}\$ & \$\small V_{DS_0}\$ for this circuit?

I know that \$\small V_{GS_0} = V_{G_0} - V_{D_1} +(-3\ \mathrm{V})\$ but I do not know which one to solve for first.

Also, what would be \$\small V_{GS_1}\$?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you notice that you know the drain current ---> Ib = Id0 = Id1 = 1mA?

Comment: Yes, but what would be \$\small V_{GS_1}\$ in that case?

Comment: \$V_{GS1}\$ is \$0 - V_{S1} = - V_{S1}\$, \$V_{GS0} = 2 - V_{S0}\$, \$V_{DS1} = V_{S0} - V_{S1}\$, and  \$V_{DS0} = V_{DD} - V_{S0}\$. You know the current through both the transistors. You have two equations and two unknowns.

Comment: Or simply ignore lambda for DC quiescent current calculations.

Comment: @sarthak Thank you!